# run global function inside slideUp

Tags: jquery, global-variables

I am using [vgrid](https://github.com/xlune/jQuery-vGrid-Plugin) plugin that comes with `vg.vgrefresh();` used to refresh the position of the tiles. I am trying to run it inside this function, but without success:

```
hideComments: function()
    {           
        this.$commentsCont.slideUp('fast');
        vg.vgrefresh();
    }
```

Somehow it works but its not refreshing the positions correctly, my best guess is that i need to run it along with `this.$commentsCont.slideUp('fast');` is there any way to break this code and run it with `vg.vgrefresh();` ? I'm lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to call this function **after** slideUp is finished then:

```
hideComments: function()
{           
    this.$commentsCont.slideUp('fast', function() {
        vg.vgrefresh();
    });
}
```

Refer to [slideUp docs](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/) for details

Comment: yup, a callback function after `slideUp` should do it